# Precise st_area() of small polygon need geography

Tags: postgis

My map is using UTM ([my SRID](https://epsg.io/31982)), so it is in meters. The `diff` shows that it is not the same.

What is the "most correct" value? 
(less floating point truncations and geometry-transformation errors)

```sql
with t AS (
 select st_area(geom) as area, st_area(ST_Transform(geom,4326),true) as area_by_geog 
 from lotes_201902 limit 10
) select *, area-area_by_geog diff from t;
```

```
        area        |    area_by_geog    |          diff
--------------------|--------------------|-------------------------
  42.44465491358426 | 42.445538004511036 |  -0.0008830909267771858
 2.4536436571955162 | 2.4536953698843718 | -5.1712688855509725e-05
  27.22972418947691 | 27.231235437648138 |   -0.001511248171226498
  540.8953519632962 |  540.9269822109491 |    -0.03163024765285627
 0.6281385728924397 | 0.6281763679580763 |  -3.779506563661439e-05
 2.4007094292112736 | 2.4008618587686215 | -0.00015242955734784402
 1610.5201813294152 | 1610.5546417832375 |    -0.03446045382224838
  875.7401393538803 |  875.7573282532394 |   -0.017188899359098286
  240.7359251995889 | 240.73819002881646 |    -0.00226482922755622
  76.26414002163474 |  76.26483199838549 |  -0.0006919767507440611
```

Comment: All the values are likely correct, they're just answering different questions. The real question is why a square millimeter is a significant difference to GIS data.

Comment: Where's the geography type here? Does transforming to 4326 cast to geography or does the two-argument form of `st_area` do it? Don't have a PostGIS handy to test at the moment. Otherwise you're comparing two geometry measures, not geography.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, it is the [guide definition](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html), when you set to `true` you can suppose that it is casting to geography, `ST_Area(geography geog, true)`. It is only possible when geometry is with no projection (4326).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in both columns are equally acceptable. The differences are actually minute and within tolerance even for cadastral survey requirements.

Much of the differences in value are due to the IEEE 754 floating point representation and rounding rules, and not floating point truncation.

---

**Continuation of same question**

*On my table of lots (with cadastral survey urban requirements), ~20% of geometries has average area of 1500 m2 and 0.2 m2 of diff. For a subset of average area of 30000 m2 the average diff is 4 m2... So the behaviour in diff/area is the same, ~0.013%. Perhaps it only changes for rural lots (farms), I can test but it is interesting to know the "limit" where we must to change the city area or farm area calculus to geografy*

Cadastre lots are always recorded in an ordinance planar coordinate system. If the polygons were obtained from the authority (e.g., land office, bureau, etc) it usually means that they had performed some cadastre network adjustment, and minimized the errors. Hence, for cadastre lots, there should be no real concern when to switch to *geography* computation.

Comment: Another question (I can open a new one)... How to check what is "small area" for change to geography? On my table of lots (with cadastral survey urban requirements), ~20% of geometries has average area of 1500 m2 and 0.2 m2 of diff. For a subset of average area of 30000 m2 the average diff is  4 m2... So the behaviour in `diff/area` is the same,  ~0.013%. Perhaps it only changes for rural lots (farms), I can test but it is interesting to know the "limit" where we must to change the city area or farm area calculus to geografy.